# Kindle Fire - Set 3rd Party Launchers' Wallpaper

Tags: launcher, amazon-kindle-fire

I've had this issue for a while now. I've rooted my Kindle Fire 2nd Generation, installed a boot animation, a custom font, and made everything the way i want it. But, when I go and switch over to Apex Launcher, there is a black wallpaper. I set the wallpaper in the menus or themes, but it doesn't work. Later, I switch over to Nova launcher, and the exact same thing happens. Is there any way to set the wallpaper for a 3rd party launcher on a Kindle Fire?